# Plot true color Sentinel-2A imagery in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gis, satellite-image, sentinel2

Through a combination of non-matlab/non-native tools (GDAL) as well as native tools (geoimread) I can ingest Sentinel-2A data either a indiviual bands or as an RGB image having employed gdal merge.  I'm stuck at a point where using

```
imshow(I, [])
```

Produces a black image, with apparently no signal.  The range of intensity values in the image are 271 - 4349.  I know that there is a good signal in the image because when I do:

```
bit_depth = 2^15;
I = swapbytes(I);
[I_indexed, color_map] = rgb2ind(I, bit_depth);
I_double = im2double(I_indexed, 'indexed');
ax1 = figure;
colormap(ax1, color_map);
image(I_double)
```

i.e. index the image, collect a colormap, set the colormap and then call the `image` function, I get a likeness of the region I'm exploring (albeit very strangely colored)

I'm currently considering whether I should try:

1. Find a low-level description of Sentinel-2A data, implement the scaling/correction
2. Use a toolbox, possibly this one.
3. Possibly adjust ouput settings in one of the earlier steps involving GDAL
   Comments or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

A basic scaling scheme is:

```
% convert image to double
I_double = im2double(I);

% scaling
max_intensity = max(I_double(:));
min_intensity = min(I_double(:));
range_intensity = max_intensity - min_intensity;
I_scaled = 2^16.*((I_double - min_intensity) ./ range_intensity);

% display
imshow(uint16(I_scaled))
```

noting the importance of casting to `uint16` from `double` for `imshow`.

Answer (score 1):

A couple points...

- You mention that `I` is an [RGB image](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-12468) (i.e. N-by-M-by-3 data). If this is the case, the `[]` argument to [`imshow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imshow.html) will have no effect. That only applies automatic scaling of the display for [*grayscale* images](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-175).
- Given the range of intensity values you list (271 to 4349), I'm guessing you are dealing with a [`uint16`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint16.html) data type. Since this data type has a maximum value of 65535, your image data only covers about the lower 16<sup>th</sup> of this range. This is why your image looks practically black. It also explains why you can see the signal with your given code: you apply [`swapbytes`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/swapbytes.html) to `I` before displaying it with [`image`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html), which in this case will shift values into the higher intensity ranges (e.g. `swapbytes(uint16(4349))` gives a value of `64784`).

In order to better visualize your data, you'll need to scale it. As a simple test, you'll probably be able to see something appear by just scaling it by 8 (to cover a little more than half of your dynamic range):

```
imshow(8.*I);
```

Comment: Thanks, @gnovice. I have updated my question to include a basic scaling scheme.  You've helped me better understand what my issue is.  The imagery/signal is clear but a little bit dark.  This thread (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233826/get-rgb-images-from-sentinel-2-using-gdal) alludes to a "cumulative count cut" and adjusting brightness, contrast and saturation.  Identifying resources to achieve these adjustments, I believe, is my next question.